# Emails and Notification are not triggered after creating FeedItem record in Apex

Tags: feeditem, chatter-feed, casefeed

After creating a FeedItem record in Apex, emails and notifications are not triggered to the person who had created the chatter FeedItem. So do I need to create a custom notification and email for this? Or am I missing something here for this, - like any permission to send emails and notifications while creating custom FeedItems?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Sender Name and Sender Email enabled in Chatter Email Settings. The notification is triggered to the person who is tagged. Sender of the chatter doesnt receive any notification even if they tag themselves or tag the group that they are part of.